# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I've been looking at the other posts on this error but can't seem to figure it out in this situation. I'm trying to save to localstorage, but I get this error and it says that the "radio" variable is undefined, but it doesn't seem to be. I'm using JQMobile as well. Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KpbLD/ 
Line 28 seems to be the problem.

Here's the function:

```
var getSelectedRadio = function(){
        var radios = document.forms[0].acoustic;
        for(var i=0, j=radios.length; i<j; i++){
            if(radios[i].checked) {
            console.log(acousticValue);
                acousticValue = radios[i].value;

            }
        }
        return acousticValue;

};
```

Comment: "Line 28 seems to be the problem"... no, the problem is that `radios` is `undefined`.

Comment: You must not be getting anything back from "document.forms[0].acoustic"

Comment: @SteveChambers getElementById is only on the document object

Answer (score 7):

You can't read properties of `undefined`. It doesn't have properties, typically (see http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/).

So, before you try to read its `length`, make sure it's not undefined. Or that it has a `length`, like

```
if (obj.length) { your code }
```

This presumes that `obj` is not `undefined`. If you're not sure about that either, then:

```
if (obj && obj.length) { your code }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.forms[0].acoustic
```

Doesn't exist and therefore is undefined.  When you set radios to that and then try to find the length, it fails.

You probably need to be looking for a different object, or at least checking to see if the object exists before attempting to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `typeof variable(radios)`. It seems to be object. This error won't come if it is an array.

Comment: Apparently problem was, that variable radios is *undefined*.  Meaning it is not an object, nor array but undefined. Also your syntax should be `typeof radios`